# One-to-One relationships in Entity Framework 7 Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

How to configure One-to-One or ZeroOrOne-to-One relationships in Entity Framework 7 Code First using Data Annotations or Fluent Api?

Comment: Read this [article](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Answer (score 25):

You can define OneToOne relationship using Fluent API in Entity Framework 7 as below

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BlogImage> BlogImages { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .HasOne(p => p.BlogImage)
            .WithOne(i => i.Blog)
            .HasForeignKey<BlogImage>(b => b.BlogForeignKey);
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public BlogImage BlogImage { get; set; }
}

public class BlogImage
{
    public int BlogImageId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    public int BlogForeignKey { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And something that wasn't obvious to me, and is no where to be found in the documentation (or I missed it), if you wanted BlogImage to have a one to zero or one relationship to Blog, instead of a one to one (i.e. a BlogImage on it's own that optionally does not reference a Blog, you merely have to make the BlogImage.BlogForeignKey nullable, like this:     public int? BlogForeignKey { get; set; }

Comment: Is this property really required? `public int BlogForeignKey { get; set; }`

Answer (score 4):

The above answer is absolutely correct.

Just for readers information: This has been explained nicely in [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)

**One-to-one**

One to one relationships have a reference navigation property on both sides. They follow the same conventions as one-to-many relationships, but a unique index is introduced on the foreign key property to ensure only one dependent is related to each principal.

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public BlogImage BlogImage { get; set; }
}

public class BlogImage
{
    public int BlogImageId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

**Note**

EF will choose one of the entities to be the dependent based on its ability to detect a foreign key property. If the wrong entity is chosen as the dependent, you can use the Fluent API to correct this.

Comment: Do I really need to define this property? `public int BlogId { get; set; }`

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin The property `public int BlogId { get; set; }` is needed because `"EF will choose one of the entities to be the dependent based on its ability to detect a foreign key property."` See the note in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships in the One-to-one section of Other Relationship Patterns.