# One to one or zero mapping in Entity Framework Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, relationship

I have a series of models that relate to a parent model, and the series of models have a child table that relates back to the original parent, so:

```
Public Class A
{
    [Key]
    public long AId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

Public Class B1
{
    [Key]
    public long Id {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("AId")]
    public virtual A a {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<C> Cs {get;set}
}

Public Class B2
{
    [Key]
    public long AId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("AId")]
    public virtual A a {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<C> Cs {get;set}
}

Public Class C
{
    public long CId {get; set;}
    public long AId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("AId")]
    public virtual A a {get;set;}
}
```

The ApplicationDBContext ties the one to one/zero entities together with fluent api, but I can't figure out how to tie c.  The context looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
    public DbSet<B1> B1s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<B2> B2s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<C> Cs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<B1>().HasOne(x => x.a).WithOne().HasForeignKey<A>(p => p.Id);
    }
```

I want to tie C in with something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<B1>().HasMany(x => x.Cs).WithOne(y => y.a);
```

But it doesn't like this because it is referencing table A, the parent, which is what I want it to do.  This is my first attempt at using Core and I am not finding a way to tie 3 tables together with fluent api.  I was able to do this in EF 4.6, so I am assuming this should be possible in Core.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does this previous answer also address your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35507286/1260204

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out....

```
modelBuilder.Entity<B1>().HasMany(x => x.Cs).WithOne().HasForeignKey(y => y.AId);
```

Hopefully this helps someone else out.